# Could tell me if "what" is needed to be changed?

Tags: free-relative-clauses

> Experimental results derived from a single subject are, therefore, of limited value; there is no way to know **what** the subject’s responses are typical or atypical of the response of humans as a group.

I think the "what" above is not natural to me and came up with these two answers: "whether" or"if".

Could you please tell me if my answers are correct?

Comment: _Experimental results derived from a single subject are, therefore, of limited value; there is no way to know if the subject’s responses are typical or atypical given/according to the response of humans as a group._ OR _Experimental results derived from a single subject are, therefore, of limited value; there is no way to know what the subject’s responses are - typical or atypical; depending on the response of humans as a group._ The sentence has to be reformed to include some words and to make sense.

Comment: "What" is incorrect. "Know" requires as complement a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) introduced by one of the interrogative subordinators "whether" and "if".

Comment: @BillJ what about "She thinks she knows what is best for her"?

Comment: .What about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Experimental results derived from a single subject are, therefore, of*
> *limited value; there is no way to know what the subject’s responses*
> *are typical or atypical of the response of humans as a group.*

"What" is incorrect here.

"Know" requires as complement a subordinate interrogative clause (embedded question) introduced by one of the interrogative subordinators "whether" and "if".

... *there is no way to know whether / if the subject’s responses are typical or atypical of the response of humans as a group*.